# From iframe system to jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, iframe

At this time I am using hidden iframes to dynamically change the content of the main page, that works fine but I want to evolve it to jQuery Ajax.

In the iframe, I generate dynamically some javascript in PHP according to some database extraction.

Example of the iframe content:

```
parent.$("#BtPeriod").html("Update of the content of a <button>...");
//Update of a variable in the main page with data from the database
parent.allAccounts = null;
parent.allAccounts = [ 
            { y: "2015-09", accounts: 813 },
            { y: "2015-10", accounts: 441 },
            { y: "2015-11", accounts: 839 },
            { y: "2015-12", accounts: 764 }
 ];
//Calling a function of the main page:
parent._allAccountsChart();
```

To make it evolve to jquery/Ajax I was thinking of using the method .ajax:

```
var values = {
    "period": "currentmonth"
};
$.ajax({
  url: "/pages/adminhome/ajax/ajax_update_charts.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: values,
   success: function(data){
    alert("success" + data);
  }
});
```

The alert display success and the content of the `ajax_update_charts.php` but does not excecute the Javascript. I saw there is also the method getScript but it's not a javascript file, it a php file generating some javascript.

How can I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: don't see how it would display anything ... you aren't doing anything to insert response in page

Comment: Also note that `parent.$` is no longer valid.

Comment: @charlietfl Yes but I don't know in Ajax how to update the var `allAccounts` and to call the function `_allAccountsChart()`. I didn't know that parent.$ is not valid anymore. It's working fine

Comment: you have to remove the `parent.`

Comment: If I put only `alert("test");` in ajax_update_charts.php, it's not executed.

Comment: try using `load()` method...it's better with embeded script.  http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: But load is to update an element like `$("#elemen").load(url);` ? I just want to execute some javascript generated in PHP.

Comment: oh...you only want script? no html? Can migrate the script to files and use getScript

Comment: The script is generated in PHP, when I do for the iframe `parent.allAccounts = [ 
            { y: "2015-09", accounts: 813 },` this value are from the database.

Comment: can get data alone by having php send json..then when you get the json you pass it to functions

Comment: Ok, I see, so it won't be that easy. I have to change many parts of my scripts (PHP and Javascript).

Comment: Oooh, I feel better. There is the Datatype option in .ajax: `dataType: "script"`, so I will just have to remove `parent.` :P

Comment: yes...and `getScript()` is just a wrapper for `$.ajax` with that set